# How can I solve "pg_dump: error: connection to server ..... FATAL: password authentication failed for user" (in pgAdmin)?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm new to PostgreSQL.  I currently have PostgreSQL and pgAdmin installed on Windows 10.  I am attempting to backup my database in pgAdmin (using this using this dialog [Backup](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/7.8/backup_dialog.html)).  In the left hand panel I right click the database, select backup, and click backup in the window.  This results in the process failing.  In the process details I see this error:

pg_dump: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "[my windows username]"
The system cannot find the path specified.

I noticed it seems to be using my windows username in the connection.  If this is the problem I do not know how to change it.

Right clicking on the server name in the pgAdmin left hand panel, I checked my connection settings and it says:  Host name/address - localhost ; Port - 5432 ; Username - postgres

I tried going into the pg_hba.conf file and changed "all" to my postgreSQL username "postgres":  "local   all    postgres    md5".  This appears to have done nothing.

Comment: Assuming you are using this dialog [Backup](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/7.8/backup_dialog.html), make sure you have selected correct *Role name*. As of now it looks like you are not specifying a role name and it falling back to use using your OS user name.

Comment: In Role name I have tried my username "postgres" and some other options.  Same result.

Comment: 1) I cannot replicate, it works for me. 2) I don't see how you can get * FATAL: password authentication failed for user "[my windows username]` if you are using `postgres` as role name.

Comment: Thanks for trying.  I can confirm in the backup dialog, Role name is set to "postgres".  It is the only option (in the Role name drop down menu) with the blue person symbol beside it.

Comment: I did a complete un-install of postgreSQL, pgAdmin, and deleted any remaining folders to have a completely clean re-install.  I tried the backup dialogue on an empty database.  I still had the same error.

Comment: I have discovered that I can successfully backup if I change the backup file location to "C:\Users\Public".  Just guessing maybe Dropbox, or Symantec, or something else could be interfering with permissions, maybe?

Comment: What is the version of pgAdmin and of PostgreSQL?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  The role name specified in that GUI element is just passed to pg_dump as `--role xxx`, which in turn is passed to PostgreSQL as `set role xxx`. That role is not the one used for authentication purposes.  For those purposes it should be using the same role as pgAdmin4 originally connected to the server with.

Comment: The pgAdmin 4 version is 7.8 (NW.js Version 0.77.0).  PostgreSQL version is 16.0.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by changing the backup file location to outside of the "C:\Users\[username]" folder.  Hope that helps someone.

Comment: While it is easy to see how trying to save it to the wrong place could fail, it is hard to see how it could cause a failure with that error message.